# .htaccess IP restricted directories and no restrictions on direct file accessing

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Basically I'm trying prevent directory listing unless IP is allowed but allow direct access to any file from outside the IP?

So far in my .htaccess I have:

```
allow from all
Options -Indexes

<Files *>
    deny from all

    # External
    allow from XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

    # Internal
    allow from XX.XX.XX.

    Options +Indexes
    DirectoryIndex README.html
</Files>
```

This allows me to list the directories and access files within our network and restrict access outside our network, but this also prevents direct access to files outside our network. I'd like to be able to access files outside the network but NOT allow directory listings.

Thanks.

---

**EDIT**

I have found this https://serverfault.com/a/531674 which could possibly help but we have an IP range and this option only allows an IP equal to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link provided in your edit your could write something like this:

```
# considering your ip range is 150.150.150.xxx
options -Indexes
<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ /150\.150\.150\.[0-9]+/">
    options +Indexes
</If>
```

---

**EDIT** for multiple ip ranges:

```
# considering you have two ip ranges 150.150.150.xxx and 250.250.250.xxx
options -Indexes
<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ /150\.150\.150\.[0-9]+/ || %{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ /250\.250\.250\.[0-9]+/">
    options +Indexes
</If>
```

You can also do the `OR` condition inside your regular expression:

```
# considering you have two ip ranges 150.150.150.xxx and 250.250.250.xxx
options -Indexes
<If "%{REMOTE_ADDR} =~ /(150\.150\.150\.[0-9]+)|(250\.250\.250\.[0-9]+)/">
    options +Indexes
</If>
```

Tested and working with Apache >= 2.4

Comment: Awesome thank you! Is it possible to do an OR condition within the IF or would I have to do something like: /(150\.150\.150\.[0-9]+)|(123\.123\.123\.[0-9]+)+/